# C# System.IO.File.Exists does not work in Unity

Tags: c#, windows, unity-game-engine, system.io.file

I am trying to locate a file on my computer so I can store my game's login data on that certain file. I have a string that contains the path.

```
public string path = "C:/Users/DevelopVR/Documents";
//DevelopVR is my username
```

Then I have this later on:

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
{
Debug.Log("Path exists on this computer");
}

else
{
Debug.LogWarning("Path does NOT exist on this computer");
}
```

I have also tried swapping out this:

```
else
{
Debug.LogWarning("Path does NOT exist on this computer");
}
```

With this:

```
else if (!System.IO.File.Exists(path))
{
Debug.LogWarning("Path does NOT exist on this computer");
}
```

But every time it logs the error. So I don't know what to do. It seems like other people are having the same problem. Thanks, If you have the answer.

Comment: try the absolute path, not simply "Documents", use "C:\Users\YourUsername\Documents"

Comment: Nope. Still outputs 'Path does NOT exist on this Computer'

Comment: Consider the *AppData* directory for config information rather than Documents.

Comment: @GraniteSOS But you are trying to check directory or file?

Comment: I am trying to check for a file

Comment: then you have to add your file name (and extension) on your path string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Documents` is a **Directory**, not a **File**, so instead of checking for `File`, check for `Directory` like:

```
if(File.Exists(path))
{
    // This path is a file
    ProcessFile(path);
}
else if(Directory.Exists(path))
{
    // This path is a directory
    ProcessDirectory(path);
}
```

Remember that if you want to search for a **File**, your `path` should have the file name and extension like:

```
public string path = @"C:/Users/DevelopVR/Documents/MyFile.txt";
```

Comment: I had to put the data being stored inside of a folder inside of a directory.

Answer (score 1):

"Documents" is not a real path, it's a convenience *link* to the 'special folder' that Windows provides.

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=netcore-3.1

```
// Sample for the Environment.GetFolderPath method
using System;

class Sample
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("GetFolderPath: {0}", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System));
    }
}
/*
This example produces the following results:

GetFolderPath: C:\WINNT\System32
*/
```

Comment: the path as specified by the question asker does actually exist

Comment: The question has been edited since I posted this answer